# repeated measures anova using minitab

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, minitab

[image]
I have to analyze repeated measures data set where each subject’s BMI is measured at several time points. I have two sets of subjects where some were given drug1 and another group of subjects is given drug2.
  With using repeated measures ANOVA first I am trying to analyze for the subjects who were given drug 1, how their BMI varies with time .After that  analyze for the subjects who were given drug 2, how their BMI varies with time.

I am using MINITAB 17 and using Stat -> ANOVA -> General Linear Model, I don’t understand what should be put in `Responses` ? Should this be `BMI`. And for `factors` I included `time`.
Is this correct?  What should be included for `covariates` field?

Comment: Is there any 'fixed effect' or 'random effect' option in minitab panel there?

Comment: This page has similar task , though in a different program : http://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#analysis_of_variance/two_way_replicate.htm%3FTocPath%3DAnalysis%2520of%2520variance|_____3S

Answer (score 2):

In 'Responses' you need to use the `BMI` as it is your interest of study.

I'm not sure, how you coded Time as 1,2,3 but if it is a factor that affects the response (BMI) then it's okay to use. You may also have to use 'Drug' & 'subject' as factors.

Covariates are quantitative variables measured on either an interval scale or ratio scale. Examples include height, weight, age, temperature, volume, pressure and so on, in fact any valid, predictor or independent variable.

It is an optional input in `Minitab`. In your case, I do not see a continuous predictor. So, you can leave it as blank. Hope this helps!